# create a input dataset for multiple types of data in a single csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I want to create a input dataset for input into TF but got stuck on this. I have a csv file of various input types( float and string). I want to create a training file for tensorflow .is there any way i could use pandas or TF function to input both types of data

```
`df = pd.read_csv("C:\TRAININGDATA\DATABASE.csv")
Labeldata = pd.DataFrame(df, columns= ['ASSEMBLY_NAME','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'])
#REMOVE DOWN IF YOU WANT ALL DATA IN CSV
#print (Labeldata)
# PRINT CSV DATA FOR THE SPECIFIC ASSEMBLY
ASSEMBLYNAME = 'scene0011_00_vh_clean_2'
labels = df.loc[df['ASSEMBLY_NAME'] == ASSEMBLYNAME]
##### Importing into tensorflow
#df['labels'] = df['ASSET NAME'].astype(float)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xygrgb , labels))
print(dataset)
```

`
here is a  sample of data

[image]
As you can see second column and last column is a string ,others are float values. I would like to input this type of data as input dataset. Any help is really appreciated.

*********EDIT************
for the following code

```
dtypes = {'ASSEMBLY_NAME': np.int64, 'ASSETID': 'float'}

df = pd.read_csv("C:\TRAININGDATA\DATABASE.csv",dtype = dtypes)
print(df.dtypes)
```

I am getting the error of `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`

and for the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\TRAININGDATA\DATABASE.csv")
df['ASSEMBLY_NAME'] = df['ASSEMBLY_NAME'].astype(float)
print(df.dtypes)
```

I am getting the error of `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'scene0002_00_vh_clean_2'`

for the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\TRAININGDATA\DATABASE.csv")
    df['ASSEMBLY_NAME'] = df['ASSEMBLY_NAME'].astype('string')
    print(df.dtypes)
```

they are getting converted to string but float value is not getting converted to tensor

```
 ASSEMBLY_NAME     string
AssetID           string
Asset Name        string
OffsetX          float32
OffsetY          float32
OffsetZ          float32
Matrix a1        float32
Matrix b1        float32
Matrix c1        float32
Matrix a2        float32
Matrix b2        float32
Matrix c2        float32
Matrix a3        float32
Matrix b3        float32
Matrix c3        float32
KeyPARAM          string
dtype: object
```

I am getting the error of

```
ValueError: Dimensions 7 and 10 are not compatible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will implicitly infer the `dtypes` for each column.

Now if for any reason you wish to explicitly specify the type for a column you can do so by providing the `dtype` argument:

```
dtypes = {'colName': np.int64, 'anotherColName': 'float'}
df = pd.read_csv('C:\TRAININGDATA\DATABASE.csv', dtype=dtypes)
```

Note though, this will lead to an error in case the column cannot be parsed using the specified dtype.

---

Alternatively, you can also post-process the dataframe:

```
df['anotherColName'] = df['anotherColName'].astype(float)
```

---

If you want to check the `dtypes` of your dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\TRAININGDATA\DATABASE.csv")
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: It is not working. When we try to convert NAN to float or string it shows a error. The dtypes of strings are inferred as objects."ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).", This is the error it is showing@Giorgos Myrianthous

Comment: @rocky Then please edit your question and share what you’ve tried to do along with the full error trace

Comment: hey I edited the question. am I missing anything @Giorgos Myrianthous